# Can refreshing a web page be controlled using ON/OFF button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

I've an Auto Refresh Button in my page. When I click Auto Refresh ON the page should reload, while the Auto Refresh OFF is selected the should not reload. Is this Possible?

Here is my Auto Refresh button Functionality:

```
$('#refresh').click(function(){
   if($('#refresh').attr('class') == 'refresh-off'){
      $('#refresh').addClass('refresh-on');
   }
    else{
      $('#refresh').removeClass('refresh-on');
   }
   });
});
```

Comment: where's the code that reloads page? Not clear how reload works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a timer, then checking the class of #refresh.  If set, then refresh the page.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fALW/show/) shows it working on a 10 second interval.

```
var int=self.setInterval(function(){refreshPage()},10000);

$(document).ready(function() {

  var hashTag = window.location.href.split('#');
  if (hashTag[1] == 'reload') {
     $('#refresh').addClass('refresh-on').html('Refresh On');  
  }

  $('#refresh').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).toggleClass('refresh-on'); 
    if ($(this).hasClass('refresh-on'))
      $(this).html('Refresh On');
    else 
      $(this).html('Refresh Off');
  });

});

function refreshPage() {
  if ($('#refresh').hasClass('refresh-on')) {
    location.hash = 'reload';
    window.location.reload();
  } else
      location.hash = '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!  But the page is loading in both classes('refresh-on' and 'refresh-off')

Comment: @RajeshPandian My bad - remove the semicolon on the end of the if statement and you should find it works as intended.

Comment: Thank You!!! When the page reloads Auto Refresh ON gets OFF :( Is there any way to switch it manually not automatically??

Comment: I have adjusted the answer, to add a hashtag to the URL.  If the tag is set, it #refresh has the class added.

Comment: Great - thanks for letting us know.  If you wanted to be more discrete, you could do the same but using a cookie rather than a hashtag - the logic would work exactly the same, just read and write the cookie, not the hashtag.  [Here is a good guide](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: :when the button is ON a particular part of my web page should get refresh. For example if I've a DIV, when the button is ON the content in this DIV should reload. If the button is OFF, the DIV should remain the same.Is that possible to refresh a particular part of a Web Page?

Comment: Yes this is possible using Ajax but outside the scope of your original question. [This tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html?m=1) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible to do so. As you'll be controlling the refresh yourself, maybe you can just make due by adding a `GET` parameter to the URL to indicate the auto-refresh in action. That means that when you've reloaded the webpage, your script should be checking to see if there's a `GET` parameter called `refresh` and act on it.

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/?refresh[=auto]
```

Answer (score 0):

set timer to refresh:

```
var timerId;
$(document).ready(function() {
    timerId = setInterval("location.reload(true)", 300000);
});
```

than clear the refresh command by

```
clearInterval(timerId);
```

complete code:

```
var timerId;
$('#refresh').click(function(){
   if($('#refresh').attr('class') == 'refresh-off'){
      $('#refresh').addClass('refresh-on');
      timerId = setInterval("location.reload(true)", 300000);
   }
    else{
      $('#refresh').removeClass('refresh-on');
      clearInterval(timerId);
   }
   });
});
```